# Input Alert Dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to use alert dialog before it will go in the register class. i want it to be  encrypted like password

```
private OnClickListener regTextClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
 //             Intent intent = new Intent(/*MainActivity.this*/view.getContext(),       Register.class);
//              startActivity(intent);
            final EditText txtUrl = new EditText(this);

            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)

            .setTitle("Moustachify Link")

            .setMessage("Paste in the link of an image to moustachify!")
            09.
            .setView(txtUrl)

            .setPositiveButton("Moustachify", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

            String url = txtUrl.getText().toString();

            moustachify(null, url);

            }

            })

            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

            .show();

        }
    };
```

i think my code is wrong. i don't know how to use alert dialog.

Comment: you can set the input type for edittext.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the input type of the editText you are showin in the dialog, something like this:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
 //             Intent intent = new Intent(/*MainActivity.this*/view.getContext(),       Register.class);
//              startActivity(intent);
            final EditText txtUrl = new EditText(this);
            txtUrl.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Moustachify Link")
            .setMessage("Paste in the link of an image to moustachify!")
            09.
            .setView(txtUrl)    
            .setPositiveButton("Moustachify", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            String url = txtUrl.getText().toString();
            moustachify(null, url);
            }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            .show();

        }
    };
```

Comment: Answers are always so much more helpful if there's some text explaining why they solve the problem.